# Feature weights

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Is there a way to give weights to features before training a neural network model? The meaning of *weight* here would be similar to that in linear regression - a representation of how much to trust each feature. This is unrelated to node weights or feature importance estimation after training.

Something similar to this [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4918).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A neural net should learn on its own what features are trustworthy.

Comment: If I correctly understood, with this technique you don't discard the less relevant weights in the `feature engineering` phase, but you make them part of your NN with some `weights` that indicate how relevant they are. I can't find an open implementation of the paper, but as they say **Our algorithm works by changing the error function of MLPs** and they provide the expression, so it shouldn't be difficult to implement.